# Saving images in Azure storage

Tags: file, azure, filesystems, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

I am building a web application , where users can upload images & videos and store them in their account. I want to store these files somewhere and save only the URL in the DB.

What is the right way to do it using Azure services? Is there a dedicated server for this, or some VM?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, there is a dedicated service for this purpose. It is the [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/). And you are highly advised to save all and any user uploaded content to that service instead to the local file system.

The provided [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) has samples for almost any language that has client SDK provided by microsoft.

If, at the end you use some platform or language that is not directly supported by an SDK, you can always refer to the [Blob Storage REST API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135733.aspx).

You will need to go through the [blob service concepts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179376.aspx) to get deeper understanding of the service and how to use it.